# IF condition not met but code still being triggered

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I've come across something really odd which I've never seen before and wondered if anyone could shed light on the issue:

The old code:

```
if ((orderFileCreationStatus.OrderFileStatus == OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.ContentCreated
        || orderFileCreationStatus.OrderFileStatus == OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.NoContent)
    && orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus != OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.Published
    && orderFileCreationStatus.PersonalisedProductFileStatus != OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.Published)
{
    webOrderHeader.OrderStatus = Domain.Duos.OrderStatus.AwaitingAuthorisation;
    webOrderHeader.AuthoriserUserId = null;
    UpdateWebOrderHeader(webOrderHeader);

    throw new Exception("Could not create the Order File for order ID: " + webOrderHeader.OrderId.ToString() + "rollback");
}
```

The new code:

```
if ((orderFileCreationStatus.OrderFileStatus == OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.ContentCreated || orderFileCreationStatus.OrderFileStatus == OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.NoContent))
{
    if(orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus != OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.Published)
    {
        if(orderFileCreationStatus.PersonalisedProductFileStatus != OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.Published)
        {
            webOrderHeader.OrderStatus = Domain.Duos.OrderStatus.AwaitingAuthorisation;
            webOrderHeader.AuthoriserUserId = null;
            UpdateWebOrderHeader(webOrderHeader);

            throw new Exception("Could not create the Order File for order ID: " + webOrderHeader.OrderId.ToString() + "rollback");
        }
    }
}
```

Now as far as resharper is concerned these two if statements are identical but here's the catch.

In the old code the debugger is skipping the first three lines nested in the IF and throwing the exception.

In the new code this works perfectly. Has anyone experienced this before and more importantly what is causing it. I'm intrigued to find out.

Comment: Did you do Clean/Rebuild of your project/solution to make sure the debugger has the most current version of your code? Skipping lines in debug mode sounds like its using an old version.

Comment: Is this a debug or release build? The debugger likes to hit lines that may or may not run in release builds, due in part to the decreased hinting/mapping in the code.

Comment: this is always false:
if(orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus != orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus)

Comment: it looks like `orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus != OrderFileCreationStatus.Status.Published` changed to `orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus != orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus` which sound kind of different

Comment: I learned that when a statement appears to be impossible, I've made an error.

Comment: Sorry guys that was slightly incorrect I've changed the new code to what it actually is I just forgot to revert after playing around with the code.

Comment: Also we tried this in both debug and release mode with a clean build each time. This was originally failing in a live environment but apparently not in all instances. Really odd.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how reflector and/or dotpeek render the two versions of the code.

Comment: If the exception in the old code is thrown, the code block was (at least partially) executed and that means that the if condition must have been true. So the if/condition is irrelevant to the problem. Especially that you said that sometimes the three lines were executed in the old code, supports this thesis. Maybe the new code fails also sometimes if executed often enough? If really not, then the problem could be related to the generating of other binaries due to changing the code, have you checked if the old code works if you change anything else in the class?

Answer (score 2):

This logic will never be true:

```
if(orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus != orderFileCreationStatus.SpecialMeasureFileStatus)
```

You're comparing the value type to itself, which will always be true, and then negating that true to false at all times.

Comment: Sorry David as I mentioned in a comment I forgot to revert my code after a play around. I've edited the second statement to how it actually reads.

Answer (score 0):

The statements are identical. The issue must lie in the version of code being run. Try breaking the If block into a new Console app and see if you can reproduce the differences again:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool A = true;
    bool B = false;
    bool C = true;
    bool D = true;

    bool result1 = (A || B) && C && D;
    Console.WriteLine("Old way: " + result1);

    bool result2 = false;
    if (A || B)
    {
        if (C)
        {
            if (D)
            {
                result2 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("New way: " + result2);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: We can't reproduce it outside this environment but if we revert the code back to how it was and run it again we get the same result. Even with a clean build.

Comment: We aren't no.

I think we plan to use dotpeek when we have a few deadlines out the way and get to the bottom of it. Ultimately I'll post the results but I'm expecting it to be displaying the same.

Comment: I would guess that your environment is somehow not loading the code that you expect it to be. Only reasonable explanation given the evidence above.